# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable using filter function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I m trying to filter out only valid emails addresses,but I getting the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/ghhs.py", line 20, in <module>
    valid=list(filter(a,email)) TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Here is the code:

```
def fun(email):
    for i in email:
        if ('@'and'.') in i:
            user,url=i.split('@')
            web,domain=url.split(".")
            if user.replace('-','').replace('_','').isalnum() is False:
                return False
            elif web.isalnum() is False:
                return False
            elif len(domain)>3:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return True
if __name__=="__main__":
    n=int(input())
    email=[raw_input() for i in range(n)]
    a=fun(email)
    valid=list(filter(a,email))
    valid.sort()
    print (valid)
```

Comment: Python 3 or python 2?  You have it tagged as both.

Comment: What do you even expect this to do? You're calling `filter` with a callback "function" that is the actual value `True` or `False` returned by your call to `fun`.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `filter` should be a function that will get called for each item in the second argument, but you are calling the function first and passing in the return value. Change your filter call to something like this:

```
valid=list(filter(fun, email))
```

**ETA**

As pointed out in the comments below `fun` has some other problems. From one, since the function passed to `filter` gets called for each item, it shouldn't been attempting to loop over its input but just accept a single email address and not a list of addresses.

Also your initial test for characters in the address is broken. Something like this will work better:

```
def fun(email):
    if ('@' in email) and ('.' in email):
        user, url = i.split('@')
        web, domain = url.split(".")
        if user.replace('-','').replace('_','').isalnum() is False:
           return False
        elif web.isalnum() is False:
            return False
        elif len(domain)>3:
            return False
        else:
           return True
```

But better yet, don't reinvent the [wheel](https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email):

```
from validate_email import validate_email

valid = list(filter(validate_email, email))
```

Comment: And additionally, remove the for loop in fun - it should handle a single element of the email list, not the whole list.

Comment: There are other problems in `fun`. the condition `('@'and'.') in i` is not at all the same thing as `'@' in i and '.' in i`.

Comment: @Turn when i m using fun at the place of a in filter ,then while printing valid i getting an empty list..can u please fix the code.